# Has anyone ever been fined for not wearing a mask in California?

Tags: united-states, california, covid-19

California has a [statewide mask order](https://covid19.ca.gov/masks-and-ppe/). I wonder if anyone has ever been fined for violating it?

Comment: in other countries: Germany just started fining anyone not wearing the mandated mask in trains and busses in almost all federal states. In Hamburg, the 17th August was the day no more warnings were given, 40 € per head are now fined to anybody violating the ordinance (ca 15% the weekend before the date). In Berlin, the fines are up to 500€ for repeat violators and within the 3 weeks before the 8th August about 200 had been handed out (but some 30000 warnings). Nordrhein-Westphalen fines 150€ even for the first offence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes.

[According to CalMatters](https://calmatters.org/health/2020/08/california-mask-order-fines/), Beverly Hills has issued at least 103 fines to an unspecified combination of individuals and businesses:

> Beverly Hills has cited 103 individuals and businesses since the city’s fines took effect, city spokesman Keith Sterling said, but he could not provide information on the amount of money involved or whether there were repeat offenders.

[According to the San Antonio Express-News](https://www.mysanantonio.com/coronavirus/article/Citations-San-Antonio-garage-owner-doesn-t-15187448.php), San Antonio has also issued many citations, including several that were clearly issued to individuals (emphasis added):

> One employee had the mask sitting on his chin after receiving a warning. *The business and employee were cited*.

> Two citations were issued, one to the the business for employees not wearing masks and *one to the owner for not wearing a mask after a warning*.

> All of the employees corrected the issue immediately, except for an American Cookie Factory employee who was not willing to wear a mask correctly. *The employee was cited* along with the three store owners.

As far as I can tell, it's up to local enforcement agencies to enforce the mask order, so cities issuing fines (possibly under their own laws implementing the order) would seem to be the primary way that fines would be issued for such violations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, bro. I must say though that by `anyone` I meant a person (to whom the mask order applies) `individuals or businesses` allows the possibility that only businesses were actually fined.

Comment: @MaxB No problem.  I've added some additional reporting and quoted a few examples where the reporting clarified that individuals were cited for mask-related violations.

Comment: Technically, this answers the question now, although I wonder if customers or pedestrians ever get fined.

Comment: There are definitely a number of individuals not currently working who were fined for violating the health orders generally (e.g., being in a closed area of a park), but it's hard to confirm without the detailed reports whether anyone not currently working was fined for the specific offense of failing to wear a mask (and sometimes it's even unclear exactly who was fined).